# Is possible the interactions between UIViewControllerRepresentable?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swiftui, uicontainerview

I saw many tutorials on SwiftUI and interfacing with UIKit, I am wondering if interactions between UIViewControllerRepresentable are possible (For example passing data), or it's better having one UIViewControllerRepresentable that has inside `UIContainerViews` which they could interact between them?
Any hints? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. Just search [swiftui+UIViewControllerRepresentable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+UIViewControllerRepresentable) - a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you're asking. [Passing data in UIViewControllerRepresentable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352016/passing-data-in-uiviewcontrollerrepresentable)

Refer to Asperi's suggestion below for many examples.